# Proper way to populate map of member objects and store one member with a smart pointer using RAII

Tags: c++, c++17

So I am pretty new to C++ and am trying to understand smart pointers and the RAII design pattern. My question is this: say I have an object that contains a map of objects. I want one object at a time to be active, that is a want a pointer that points to one of the objects from the map. What is a proper RAII way to go about it using smart pointers? Below is what I have tried so far.

```
//StateMachine.h
    std::unique_ptr<GameObject> p1Paddle = std::make_unique<GameObject>(Paddle());
    std::unique_ptr<GameObject> p2Paddle = std::make_unique<GameObject>(Paddle());
    std::unique_ptr<GameObject> ball = std::make_unique<GameObject>(Ball());
```

```
//StateMachine.cpp
StateMachine::StateMachine()
{
    gameObjects["p1Paddle"] = std::pair <bool, std::unique_ptr<GameObject>>(false, std::move(p1Paddle));
    gameObjects["p2Paddle"] = std::pair <bool, std::unique_ptr<GameObject>>(false, std::move(p2Paddle));
    gameObjects["ball"] = std::pair <bool, std::unique_ptr<GameObject>>(false, std::move(ball));
}

void StateMachine::ChangeState(std::string key)
{
    activeObject = std::move(gameObjects[key]);
}
```

Comment: Unless you want `activeObject` to be able to destroy the object, I wouldn't use a smart pointer for it at all.

Comment: I don't see the map. Is `gameObjects` a `map`? How is it declared? You could just put the objects in a `vector` and use an iterator or index to keep track of the active object. If you have a map, you could use an iterator to the active element.

Comment: You could maintain an active iterator from the map which points to the object you have. And your code itself has a bug right now that `map::operator[]` inserts new entry for a missing key.

Comment: If you are only interested in one object at a specific moment in time from some kind of container, then perhaps it might be better to implement a priority queue based on some kind of priority... With that, you would only need a vector of objects that contain or store them and a queue that will index into that vector from a priority value... Then you wouldn't necessarily need `smart pointers` and the `vector`'s constructor is already `RAII` capable.

Comment: ConnorP: When you post a question you are very likely to get some questions requiring clarification from you. This often happens within minutes - our perhaps within an hour. If you post a question and walk away - and expect to come back to a perfect answer you will often be disappointed.

Comment: A little bit more of an explanation of what I ultimately want to do. I want to create a finite state machine where any state can be switched to at any time. States would be stored as objects and there would be a pointer to the active state.

Comment: @ConnorP You don't seem particularly interested in getting an answer to your question I must say. I asked how `gameObjects` is declared and you've also gotten an answer by  Francis Cugler that you didn't even comment on. Make a [mcve] to clear things up if Francis' answer doesn't help.

Comment: This needs to be closed/deleted. @ConnorP dropped it and doesn't show any interest in it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `map` and `smart-pointer` and based on your requirements that you only want a single object type at a given moment of time, perhaps you want a `priority queue` based implementation instead...

Here's a pseudo implementation:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum class ComponentType {
    PADDLE,
    BALL
};

class Component {
protected:
    ComponentType type_;
    uint32_t id_;
    priority_;

    Component(ComponentType type, uint32_t id, float priority) 
     : type_{type}, id_{id}, priority_{prioity};
public:
    virtual ~Component() {}
    auto type() const { return type_; }
    auto id() const { return id_; }
    auto priority() const { return priority_; }
    
    void updatePriority(float newPriority) { priority_ = newPriority; }         
};

class Paddle : public Component {
private:
    std::string name_;
public:
    Paddle(std::string_view name, float priority) :
      Component(ComponetType::PADDLE, std::stoi(name.data()), priority),
      name_{name} 
    {}

    auto name() const { return name_; }
};

class Ball : public Component {
private:
    std::string name_;
public:
    Ball(std::string_view name, float priority) :
      Component(ComponentType::BALL, std::stoi(name.data()), priority),
      name_{name}
    {}

    auto name() const { return name_; }
};

class CmpFunc {
public:
    int operator(){ const Component& a, const Component& b) {
        return a.priority() > b.priority();
    }
};

class Game {
private:
    //std::vector<Component*> components_;
    std::priority_queue<Component*, std::vector<Component*>, CmpFunc> priority_;
public:
    void initialize() {
        Paddle paddle1("paddle_1", 0.1f);
        Paddle paddle2("paddle_2", 0.2f);
        Ball ball("ball", 0.3f");
        addComponent(&paddle1);
        addComponent(&paddle2);
        addComponent(&ball);
    }

    void addComponent(Component* component) {
        if (component == nullptr)
           throw std::runtime_exception( "invalid component pointer!" );

        //components_.push_back(component);
        priority_.push(component);            
    }

    auto getComponent() {
        if (!priority_.empty()) {
            auto component = priority_.top();
            priority_.pop();
            /*components_.erase(
              std::remove(components_.begin(), components_.end(), component), 
              components_.end()
            );*/
            return component;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

This is just a pseudo example code to show a priority queue... I didn't show any implementation of updating or changing the priority queue of an object, nor did I show, how to directly use it based on some `state X` of the game or `finite-state-machine`... That would be an exercise for you...

I can not say whether this code will compile and run since I typed it out right here and have not yet tested it hence the `pseudo` code. You can play around with it and try to get it to compile and from there expand it to fit your own needs...